# Php query to get data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, database-design

Here I have an mysql tables with ID, ID_polja, lat, lng:
[image]

As you can see I want to get first data from unique number so first (lat,lng) with ID_polja =1

first (lat,lng) with ID_polja = 2 ...

But how to run a query for that?

```
SELECT * FROM koordinate WHERE ID_polja=[1,2,3... n]
```

Comment: use DISTINCT with sql query

Comment: try DISTINCT keywords

Comment: how>.........please help me

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `GROUP` and `ORDER`:

```
SELECT * FROM `koordinate` GROUP BY `ID_polja` ORDER BY `ID` ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `koordinate` GROUP BY `ID_polja`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT INSTINCT ID_polja, ID, lat, Ing FROM koordinate
```

Thats the simplest solution. If you would use `WHERE ID_polja IN [1,2,3]` you would have to count each and every number and it would still select every entry.

Comment: `INSTINCT`? i have never seen this in a SQL!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM koordinate GROUP BY ID_polja;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM `koordinate` group by ID_polja;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you need unique data of lat and long from multiple ID_polja.

So try below query :-

SELECT * FROM koordinate WHERE ID_polja IN (1,2,3,...N) GROUP BY ID_polja;

OR

If you do not have any where condition you should use below query :-

SELECT * FROM koordinate GROUP BY ID_polja;